# Jtable update selected row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a jtable that has a edit button, when i select a row and clicked to edit button and edit fields, and click to save button, that row doesn't update, And i have to refresh my table to Change that row!

My code:

```
        if (e.getSource() == editButton) {
        selectedRow = uTable.getSelectedRow();
        if (selectedRow >= 0) {
            editUser(selectedRow);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select a row");
        }
    }

    public void editUser(int row) {
    UserInformation userInf = userModel.getSelectedMember(row);
    NewUserFrame_Edit edit = new NewUserFrame_Edit(userInf, row);
}

...
```

My NewUserFrame_Edit Class :

```
public class NewUserFrame_Edit extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private AllUser userModel;
private int selectedrow;
private String gender;

public NewUserFrame_Edit(AllUser userModel,UserInformation userinf, int row) {
...
this.userModel = userModel;
    jTextField1.setText(userinf.getFname().toString().trim());
    jTextField2.setText(userinf.getLname().toString().trim());

    if (userinf.getGender().equals("Male")) {
        jRadioButton1.setSelected(true);
    } else {
        jRadioButton2.setSelected(true);
    }

    jTextField3.setText(userinf.getDate());
    selectedrow = row;
    setVisible(true);
}

private void updateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {     
    userinf = new UserInformation();

    userinf.setFname(jTextField1.getText());
    userinf.setLname(jTextField2.getText());
    userinf.setGender(gender);
    userinf.setDate(jTextField3.getText());

    userModel.setValueAt(userinf.getFname() , selectedrow, 1);
    userModel.setValueAt(userinf.getLname() , selectedrow, 2);
    userModel.setValueAt(userinf.getGender(), selectedrow , 3);
    userModel.setValueAt(userinf.getDate() , selectedrow, 4);
    userModel.updateFile(userModel.Udata);

    NewUserFrame_Edit.this.dispose();
}
...
}
```

My setValueAt() and updateFile() methods of my model Class:

```
public class AllUser extends AbstractTableModel {
...
    @Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    UserInformation userInfo = Udata.get(rowIndex);
    switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            userInfo.setID((String) value);
            break;
        case 1:
            userInfo.setFname((String) value);
            break;
        case 2:
            userInfo.setLname((String) value);
            break;
        case 3:
            userInfo.setGender((String) value);
            break;
        case 4:
            userInfo.setDate((String) value);
            break;
    }
    fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
}

    public void updateFile(ArrayList<UserInformation> data) {
    PrintWriter pw;
    try {
        pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("AllUserRecords.txt"));
        for (UserInformation userinf : data) {
            String line = userinf.getID()
                    + "     " + userinf.getFname()
                    + "     " + userinf.getLname()
                    + "     " + userinf.getGender()
                    + "     " + userinf.getDate();

            pw.println(line);
        }
        pw.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    }
}
...
}
```

When i select a row and click to edit button, a new jframe is open that its text field is fill with older data, and i update data and click to save button.
Thus, my column is not certain.
I select a entire row, Not a cell!

Thanks.

Comment: yeah..Sajjad , I had today pointed out this behaviour in your code. You can create a method called `updateRow(int index)` and within it set new Value for each cell for that row using `setValueAt(newValue,row,index)`. And within overridden `setValue` method of `TableModel` write `fireTableCellUpdated(row, col)`

Comment: Oh' Hi dear @VishalK , Are you review my whole project?

Comment: Hi @Sajjad: You have done good job in it..except some minor mistakes.. And this is the one that I found out. And regarding your project level..It still needs little amendments and then would be all fine...

Comment: Where is your code for `updateFile()` in `AllUser` class.?

Comment: Wait..let me check your method..and I update my post..

Comment: @VishalK I hade a question on installing oracle 11g release2:

Comment: I finally buy Oracle 11g Release 2 dvd to install on my laptop.
My system is 64bit windows seven . 

I want to install oracle 11g on windows, But i Think that it is better that install on linux!

But i don't familiar with linux.

Comment: When i want to install in windows, which item should i select?

Standard edition
Standard edition one
enterprise edition
personal edition


?

Comment: It all depends upon your need. As far as I guess you need Standard edition for now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a method called `updateRow(int index,String[] values)` within your `AbstractModel` extending class and within it set new Value for each cell for that row using setValueAt(newValue,row,index). And within overridden `setValue` method of `TableModel` write fireTableCellUpdated(row, col).

Consider the Code Given below. Look at the `updateRow` and `setValueAt` method in `MyModel` class. And watch `((MyModel)myModel).updateRow(row,values);//update row` written in `MyMouseAdapter` class.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

class TableRowEdit extends JFrame  
{
    private JTable table;
    private JScrollPane jsPane;
    private TableModel myModel;
    private JPanel dialogPanel;
    private JTextField tf[];
    private JLabel     lbl[];
    public void prepareAndShowGUI()
    {
        myModel = new MyModel();
        table = new JTable(myModel);
        jsPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(new LabelCellRenderer());
        table.addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapter());
        getContentPane().add(jsPane);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        prepareDialogPanel();
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

    }
    private void prepareDialogPanel()
    {
        dialogPanel = new JPanel();
        int col = table.getColumnCount() - 1;
        dialogPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(col,2));
        tf = new JTextField[col];
        lbl = new JLabel[col];
        for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
        {
            lbl[i] = new JLabel(table.getColumnName(i));
            tf[i] = new JTextField(10);
            dialogPanel.add(lbl[i]);
            dialogPanel.add(tf[i]);
        }
    }
    private void populateTextField(String[] s)
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < s.length ; i++ )
        {
            tf[i].setText(s[i]);
        }
    }
    public class LabelCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer 
    {
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,Object oValue, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) 
        {
            Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, oValue,isSelected, hasFocus,row, column);
            String value = (String)oValue;
            JLabel label =(JLabel)c;
            label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
            label.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
            label.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingUtilities.CENTER);
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingUtilities.CENTER);
            label.setText(value);
            return label;
        }
    }

    private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter
    {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt)
        {
            int x = evt.getX();
            int y = evt.getY();
            int row = table.rowAtPoint(new Point(x,y));
            int col = table.columnAtPoint(new Point(x,y));
            if (col == 2)
            {
                String arr[] = new String[table.getColumnCount() - 1];
                for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++)
                {
                    arr[i] = (String)table.getValueAt(row,i);
                }
                populateTextField(arr);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TableRowEdit.this,dialogPanel,"Information",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                String[] values = new String[tf.length];
                for (int i = 0 ; i < tf.length ; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = tf[i].getText();
                }
                ((MyModel)myModel).updateRow(row,values);//update row 
            }
        }
    }
    private class MyModel extends AbstractTableModel 
    {
        String[] columns = {
                            "Roll No.",
                            "Name",
                            "Action"
                            };
        String[][] inData = {
                                {"1","Anthony Hopkins","Edit"},
                                {"2","James William","Edit"},
                                {"3","Mc. Donald","Edit"}
                            };
        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col)
        {
            inData[row][col] = (String)value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row,col);
        }
        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col)
        {
            return inData[row][col];
        }
        @Override
        public int getColumnCount()
        {
            return columns.length;
        }
        @Override 
        public int getRowCount()
        {
            return inData.length;
        }
        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col)
        {
            return columns[col];
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row ,int col)
        {
            return true;
        }
        //This method updates the Row of table
        public void updateRow(int index,String[] values)
        {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < values.length ; i++)
            {
                setValueAt(values[i],index,i);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String st[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                TableRowEdit td = new TableRowEdit();
                td.prepareAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Everything was fine with your original code. Keep the code as it was initially. The only problem was line `userModel = new AllUser();`  in method `updateButtonActionPerformed`. It was creating new object of `AllUser` instead of using the current one. So you should remove this line from `updateButtonActionPerformed` . and change the `NewUserFrame_Edit` constructor as follows:

```
public NewUserFrame_Edit(AllUser userModel/*Add this parameter*/,UserInformation userinf, int row) {
...
    this.userModel = userModel;
    jTextField1.setText(userinf.getFname().toString().trim());
    jTextField2.setText(userinf.getLname().toString().trim());

    if (userinf.getGender().equals("Male")) {
        jRadioButton1.setSelected(true);
    } else {
        jRadioButton2.setSelected(true);
    }

    jTextField3.setText(userinf.getDate());
    selectedrow = row;
    setVisible(true);
}
```

change your as `updateButtonActionPerformed` follows:

```
private void updateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    //userModel = new AllUser();//Comment it.
    userinf = new UserInformation();

    userinf.setFname(jTextField1.getText());
    userinf.setLname(jTextField2.getText());
    userinf.setGender(gender);
    userinf.setDate(jTextField3.getText());

    userModel.setValueAt(userinf.getFname() , selectedrow, 1);
    userModel.setValueAt(userinf.getLname() , selectedrow, 2);
    userModel.setValueAt(userinf.getGender(), selectedrow , 3);
    userModel.setValueAt(userinf.getDate() , selectedrow, 4);
    userModel.updateFile(userModel.Udata);

    NewUserFrame_Edit.this.dispose();
}
```

And change`editUser(int row)` method of class `UserPage` as follows:

```
public void editUser(int row)
{
    UserInformation userInf = userModel.getSelectedMember(row);
    NewUserFrame_Edit edit = new NewUserFrame_Edit(userModel,userInf, row);
}
```

Here is your `updateFile` methd:

```
public void updateFile(ArrayList<UserInformation> data) {
    PrintWriter pw;
    try {
        pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("AllUserRecords.txt"));
        for (UserInformation userinf : data) {
            String line = userinf.getID()
                    + "     " + userinf.getFname()
                    + "     " + userinf.getLname()
                    + "     " + userinf.getGender()
                    + "     " + userinf.getDate();

            pw.println(line);
        }
        pw.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Should i use fireTableCellUpdated() method in every setValueAt() methods?

Comment: You have only one `setValueAt` defined within your `AbstractTableModel` overridden class. just write that `fireTableCellUpdated` method at that place only. Yes , you should use SwingUtilities.invokeLater for doing some change in GUI . But if you are doing changes in EDT like `actionPerformed` then you don't need this..

Comment: @Sajjad: Firstly you create a blank object of `UserInformation` say `obj`. After you do required changes in  the `textfields` of editbox with and click OK fill the corresponding fields of `obj` with corresponding textfield value.. And then call `updateRow(index,obj)`  where `index` is the index number of edited row. I hope this makes it clear now to you.

Comment: @Sajjad- Whatever I had posted in example code is just demo..It tells you the dynamics of how to update the JTable on making some change. You do'nt have to copy it exactly..

Comment: Admin just can not change a selected row id number, Just can change fName and Lname and Gender and date.

Comment: @Sajjad: in your original question the code that you posted..is'nt it working correctly when you calling `firetablecellupdated` in `setValueAt` ?

Comment: Is'nt working correctly mean that i need to refresh to see my jtable update

Comment: Ok, Now i send you whole three classes

Comment: @Sajjad- post is updated..Have a look at it..I hope this would solve your problem. And kindly delete the lots of comments that you have posted here .just to keep overall post clean.. Just Keep the relevant comment . I am deleting mine too..

Comment: @Sajjad-I had mentioned that don't change your previous old code.. just roll back what i had told you earlier... your previous old code was fine. Within  that code make the changes as I had told you to do in the end of my post

Comment: You mean the one that you had sent me?

Comment: should i change my setValue and getVlaue methods as your methods?

Comment: you should just add `fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);` in the last of `setValueAt` method

Comment: ok. .. Now your `JTable` contents are changed after updating the fields?

Comment: No, now if i refresh my jtbale , make no change at all !!

Comment: `editUser` have you made changes in it what I had told you? Pls read the last part of my answer thoroughly..Which I have written after **UPDATE**

Comment: I really am grateful to you, you've been a big help to me

Comment: ahh i see..Well I am glad to be of your help. Now kindly make this post more clean by deleting the comments of less importance below this answer.. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26774/discussion-between-vishal-k-and-sajjad)

Comment: It depends.. I have suggested you this so that a user can't select more than one row at a time in `JTable`.

Comment: If we don't write this statement , What is default status?

Comment: then it is MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION

Comment: Hi, vishal k , I have new question on here, Please see it!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477549/create-a-shortcut-in-my-table-that-do-the-same-thing-that-my-button-do

Answer (score 6):

For changing `JTable` entries, use [TableModel#setValueAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#setValueAt%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29). Calling `fireTableDataChanged` is unnecessary. This is for use internally within `TableModel` itself.

```
if (selectedRow >= 0) {
    ...
    userModel.setValueAt(newValue, selectedRow, 0);
     //        ...   more values for columns    1, 2, 3, etc.
} ...
```

Comment: I use setVlaueAt method on my table model Class.

Comment: where should use this statement?

Comment: After "Save" button clicked?

Comment: I think that the thrid argument of method is selected column, ok?

Comment: when i select a row and clicked to edit button, a new jframe is open and when i edit my text fields and click to save button, new data should be update.

Comment: But, my setValueAt method arguments is like this:

Comment: public void setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)

Comment: It is not clear which column is selected, only the number of rows is known

Comment: This will depend on your `ListSelectionModel`. Most likely you are using a `SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION`. You will need to determine, the values for each column.

Comment: That is a different matter for a new post I think :)

Comment: Now this answer makes no sense as it doesnt match the updated question . Rather than changing the nature of the question, please post a new question

Answer (score 1):

Another way to implement changes through JTable is to use the code template below:

```
    table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener(){

        /**
         * Called when table has been changed.
         */
        @Override
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
            int row = e.getFirstRow();
            int column = e.getColumn();
            TableModel model = (TableModel) e.getSource();

            String newdata = (String) model.getValueAt(row, column);
            model.setValueAt(newdata, row, column);
            // do your update with the newdata variable.
        }
    });
```

Here you can use the actual event to get the row and column of the cell that has been changed in the JTable variable.