# Custom AbstractTableModel not displaying data correctly

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I want to extract data from a table in the database based on the columns I specify using an AbstractTableModel. There are 8 columns in the table but want to only show 3 of the 8 columns.

For example:

The database has these columns: ID, First_Name, Last_Name, ...., Phone_Number. If I specify that I want to display First_Name, Last_Name, Phone_Number in the table it shows me ID, First_Name, and Last_Name. I think I should specify the index of the column name from the database to display the correct column but do not know how to implement that in my custom AbstractTableModel class.

```
public class PhysicianModelController extends AbstractTableModel 
{
    PhysicianBroker pb = PhysicianBroker.getPhysicianBroker();

private String[] columnNames =  {"First Name", "Last Name", "Phone Number"};

private ArrayList<Physician> ph = pb.getAllPhysicians();

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return ph.size();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return columnNames.length;
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int col)
{
    System.out.println(col);
    return columnNames[col];
}   

@Override
public String getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {  
    System.out.println(rowIndex + " : " + columnIndex);
    Physician p = ph.get(rowIndex);
    switch (columnIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            return Integer.toString(p.getEmployeeId());                
        case 1:
            return p.getFirstName();
        case 2:
            return p.getLastName();
        case 3:
            return p.getBirthDate();
        case 4:
            return p.getStartDate();
        case 5:
            return p.getEndDate();
        case 6:
            return p.getAddress();
        case 7:
            return p.getPhoneNumber();
        default:
            return "Incorrect input";                          
    }
}

public void addRow(Physician p) 
{
    ph.add(p);
    int row = ph.size();
    fireTableRowsInserted(row,row);
    fireTableDataChanged();
}

@Override
public Class getColumnClass(int c)
{
    return getValueAt(0,c).getClass();
}
```

}

I have overridden the getRowCount(), getColumnCount(), getColumnName(), getValueAt(), and getColumnClass() methods with my implementation. Everything works correctly once I supply all the columns from the database table.

Would someone be kind enough to lend me a hand on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Added my custom AbstractTableModel class. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: What exact error are you getting?

Comment: You have not overridden `setValueAt` method

Comment: @VishalK I think `setValueAt` is used only when editing the table cells manually.

Comment: @wojg21 since all the columns of type `String`, why not using `return String.class;` inside `getColumnClass()`? Also, `getValueAt()` should have only 3 switch-cases.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: yeah you are right..but watch at `getValueAt` method, He got only 3 columns but he is testing for 7 cases..

Comment: To elaborate, I display only three columns, but once I click on a row I get the rest of the information in textfields where i can edit the data.

Comment: @wojg21: So you mean that when you click that row a new DialogBox will having `JTextFields` containing the other information that you are not showing in `JTable`. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch your `getValueAt` method. You have only three columns . So you should return the value according to that. What was happening that for column 0 you was getting employee id whereas you wanted Firstname..So on...

```
@Override
public String getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {  
    System.out.println(rowIndex + " : " + columnIndex);
    Physician p = ph.get(rowIndex);
    switch (columnIndex)
    {

        case 0:
            return p.getFirstName();
        case 1:
            return p.getLastName();
        case 2:
            return p.getPhoneNumber();
        default:
            return "Incorrect input";                          
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Here is a code demo to add a row in JTable. Have a look on it:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.util.*;
class Person
{
    String name;
    String roll;
    String subject;
    public Person(String name,String roll,String subject)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.roll = roll;
        this.subject = subject;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public String getRoll()
    {
        return roll;
    }
    public String getSubject()
    {
        return subject;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setRoll(String roll)
    {
        this.roll = roll;
    }
    public void setSubject(String subject)
    {
        this.subject = subject;
    }
}
class TableRowAdd extends JFrame  
{
    private JTable table;
    private JScrollPane jsPane;
    private MyModel myModel;
    private JPanel dialogPanel;
    private JTextField tf[];
    private JLabel     lbl[];
    private JButton    button;
    JDialog dialog;
    public void prepareAndShowGUI()
    {
        myModel = new MyModel();
        table = new JTable(myModel);
        jsPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        button = new JButton("Add");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
            {
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(button,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        getContentPane().add(jsPane);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        prepareDialogPanel();
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

    }
    private void prepareDialogPanel()
    {
        dialogPanel = new JPanel();
        int col = table.getColumnCount();
        dialogPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(col,2));
        tf = new JTextField[col];
        lbl = new JLabel[col];
        for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
        {
            lbl[i] = new JLabel(table.getColumnName(i));
            tf[i] = new JTextField(10);
            dialogPanel.add(lbl[i]);
            dialogPanel.add(tf[i]);
        }
        dialog = new JDialog(this,"Enter details",true);
        dialog.getContentPane().add(dialogPanel);
        JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
        dialog.getContentPane().add(okButton,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        okButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
            {
                dialog.dispose();
                myModel.addRow(new Person(tf[0].getText(),tf[1].getText(),tf[2].getText()));
            }
        });
        dialog.pack();
    }
    private class MyModel extends AbstractTableModel 
    {
        String[] columns = {
                            "Roll No.",
                            "Name",
                            "Subject"
                            };
        ArrayList<Person> inData = new ArrayList<Person>()
                            {
                                {
                                    add(new Person("1","Anthony Hopkins","CS01"));
                                    add(new Person("2","James William","CS02"));
                                    add(new Person("3","Mc. Donald","CS03"));
                                }
                            };
        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col)
        {
            Person person = inData.get(row);
            switch(col)
            {
                case 0: 
                    person.setRoll((String)value);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    person.setName((String)value);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    person.setSubject((String)value);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid col");

            }
            fireTableCellUpdated(row,col);
        }
        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col)
        {
            Person person = inData.get(row);
            switch(col)
            {
                case 0: 
                    return person.getRoll();
                case 1:
                    return person.getName();
                case 2:
                    return person.getSubject();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public int getColumnCount()
        {
            return columns.length;
        }
        @Override 
        public int getRowCount()
        {
            return inData.size();
        }
        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col)
        {
            return columns[col];
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row ,int col)
        {
            return true;
        }
        //This method adds a row to the table
        public void addRow(Person person)
        {
            inData.add(person);
            fireTableRowsInserted(inData.size() - 1 ,inData.size() - 1);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String st[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                TableRowAdd td = new TableRowAdd();
                td.prepareAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense but will I be able to get the rest of the data (birth_date, start_date, end_date, etc) when I click on the row of the table? I need the rest of the data for editing in case there is a mistake?

Comment: @mKorbel: you are here for quite many days..have you any idea that why my reputations not increasing with upvotes?

Comment: @wojg21: In that case you should create a new DialogBox or any other GUI which popup when you click on a row..and it has 8 textfields with values populated from your arraylist..and after you change the data within it make the corresponding change in arraylist too..and change in JTable also..

Comment: @Vishal K every posters here can get only 200 points (20 x upvotes) per one day from upvotes, other point are (moreover) from accepting, bounties and upvoters to own question, phaaa congrats, [detailed list is](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation)

Comment: @VishalK: Thanks for the very quick input. Would I be able to populate the textfields from this class or would I need to create a new class to just do that?

Comment: @mKorbel ahha thanks for congrats ;).. So I would have to look for my answers to be accepted..;)

Comment: not you can to see only you own profile, or users profile that is currently logged in SO, link is the same for all users, I can see there only my posts

Comment: @Vishal K [once time I was idiot, with the same question too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109392/missing-reputation) :-) .....

Comment: @wojg21: you can populate the textfields from this same class via the arrayList that you are getting from `getPhysicianBroker` method. create separate method in you class there open a `JDialog` containing 8 fields, Keep ID field disabled..And populate the fields by the arraylist.get(rowindex) method and after you make changes in JTextfield values, and click ok use `setValueAt()` method of `AbstractTableModel` ...

Comment: @wojg21: See the example that I have posted in this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/15555696/1981279.. Just copy the code written above **UPDATE** section and run it. You would come to know . I hope it might help you.

Comment: I have included an addRow(Physician p) {...} method to add the row to the arrayList and I run the fireTableRowsInserted(row,row) to repaint the row added but do not get a change at all? What do you think i am doing wrong?

Comment: @wojg21: where have you added this method?

Comment: @VishalK: inside PhysicianModelController class

Comment: @wojg21 pls .put that method in your post..I want to have a look at it.

Comment: use `fireTableRowsInserted(row - 1,row - 1);` instead.

Comment: @VishalK: Just tried it and the JTable does not add that row. When I close the program and run it again the new row appears in the table.

Comment: @wojg21: Do you mean when you close the window containing JTable and then reopen it then the row is visible..?

Comment: @wojg21:Since I don't have your entire code..So I am posting here a simple demo of code .. It does exactly what you are looking for..have a look on it ..

Comment: @VishalK: YES!! It is working now. I was creating a new instance of the abstract table model in the constructor and in the panel where my table is located. Now that I have removed that addRow is functioning correctly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @wojg21 I am so glad that it helped you to sort out your problem..my pleasure..:) And StackOverflow always welcomes you :)